# android grid view display caption below each grid

Tags: android, grid

I want to display some text below each grid image.

Please see my code below.
Please help me in finding why its not working
I am getting the images properly displayed but no text
if i try to display text within image its coming
so it should be something with the layout defined. but i am not able to debug

adaptor code :

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.griditems, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
    Log.i(TAG, holder.text1.toString());
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);


            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            holder.image.setImageResource(gridItemIds[position]);
            holder.text1.setText(gridTitles[position]);
        //holder.image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        // holder.image.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

    convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(Utils
                .getLayoutParameter(), Utils.getLayoutParameter()));

        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    ImageView image;

}



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/GridItem"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  >

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </ImageView>

   <TextView android:id="@+id/grid_item_text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="TextView"
      android:textColor="#000000"
      >
   </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

gridview :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <TextView android:id="@+id/text1view" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:background="@drawable/title_bar" 
            />

        <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/gridview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:verticalSpacing="50dip"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" android:numColumns="3"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1view" 
                         android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:background="@drawable/home_bg"
                        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should add the code of R.layout.griditems

Comment: i have added both xml file content. Thank you

Comment: I added an answer, I wrote another adapter (very simple) and used your layout with a fixed image, it works correctly...

Comment: its working with your code. CAn you please tell why its not working with the baseadaptor . Whatever examples i have seen they are doing similar to what i have done. SO i wanted to know ifi missed anything. Thanks a lot for you solution and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your xml but with a simple array adapter that I wrote and everything work perfectly, try to replace your adapter with mine and let me know, thanks.

```
class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public ItemsAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.griditems, list);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View row, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final String item = getItem(position);

        ItemWrapper wrapper = null;
        if (row == null) {
            row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.griditems, parent, false);
            wrapper = new ItemWrapper(row);

            row.setTag(wrapper);
        } else {
            wrapper = (ItemWrapper) row.getTag();
        }
        wrapper.refreshData(item);

        return row;
    }

}    

static class ItemWrapper {

    TextView text;
    ImageView img;

    public ItemWrapper(View row) {
        text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
        img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    }

    public void refreshData(String item) {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_1);
        text.setText(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try using RelativeLayout too, placing the TextView underneath the ImageView by using

```
 android:layout_below="@id/grid_item_image"
```

It'll place it underneath the image, however, if you have the option to use the Graphical Layout, dragging it where you want it in conjunction with the image will set all the parameters for you instead of typing them out.